# Локализация приложения Android

Tags: android, java

Доброй ночи всем, писал приложение и тут стал вопрос о локализации, нашел один пример, но как заюзать, не пойму, вот он пример: [локализация приложений](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php).

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, как сделать, что бы язык зависил от версии языка на самом телефоне? Все стринг файлы есть, так что нужно только вот это сделать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Он и зависит. Создавайте соответствующие директории с названием локалей необходимых, подцепятся автоматом.

- res/values/strings.xml - дефолтные надписи
- res/values-ru_rRU/strings.xml - русские надписи
- res/values-en/strings.xml - английские надписи

аналогично для картинок и проч.

[Вот](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) таблица с возможными суффиксами, среди которых не только локаль может присутствовать но и другие параметры.

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался